# Codeigniter query profiler with multiple database connection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter 2.0++ or specifically 3.0-dev. The thing is I have multiple database connection and the profiler only shows query from the default connection `$this->db`.

```
class table_m extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent :: __construct(); 
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('production', TRUE);
    }

    function sel_pameran($ukmper=NULL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * from table1";

        $query = $this->db2->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

This query won't be shown in the profiler because it uses `$this->db2`. So how do make the profiler shows every query that is executed, doesn't matter from which database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question.  It's a **much simpler solution**.
[How can I display my database queries in the Codeigniter Profiler when I load my databases in my models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423245/how-can-i-display-my-database-queries-in-the-codeigniter-profiler-when-i-load-my)

Simply store your databases to the main CI class and the profiler will be able to access them.

```
function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $CI =& get_instance();
    if( is_null( $CI->Companies_db ) )
        $CI->Companies_db =& $this->load->database( 'companies', TRUE, TRUE );          

}
```

Comment: If you're lucky, without further tweaking, this will work flawlessly. And it's 2.X compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was using a local mysql database and also accessing a remote Oracle database. The Oracle queries were not being shown in the profiler.

This article helped me to fix the problem:

http://www.gotphp.com/codeigniter-multiple-database-support/5468/

Comment: Here is an updated version of the post that fixes this for newer versions of Codeigniter: http://www.gotphp.com/codeigniter-profiler-extended/54358/