# How can I display my database queries in the Codeigniter Profiler when I load my databases in my models?

Tags: codeigniter, profiling, profiler

My Codeigniter system uses multiple databases.  I don't need every database on every page, so I load each connection in the model where it's needed, then load the required models within each controller.  The profiler does not display any of the queries from these databases when I load things this way.

This is how I load the databases in my models:

```
$this->Companies_db = $this->load->database( 'companies', TRUE, TRUE );
```

I used to load all my databases in MY_Controller() ( an extension of the core controller ).  When I load them there, the profiler works fine.  When I load them in my models, it displays no database queries.

The database queries are being compiled in the method `_compile_queries()` within `system/libraries/Profiler.php`. When my databases are loaded in the model, their objects are not loading into the CI object.  The code below is the first few lines from the `_compile_queries()` method and is where this is happening.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($this->CI) as $CI_object)
    {
        if (is_object($CI_object) && is_subclass_of(get_class($CI_object), 'CI_DB') )
        {
            $dbs[] = $CI_object;
        }
    }
```

**How do I get the CI profiler to display my queries when I load my databases in my models?**  Or, more specifically, how do I get my database objects to load into the main CI object when the databases are loaded in the models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would get an instance of the CI-object and store your database there, so that is also available to the profiler.

```
class My_Model {
     private $Companies_db;

     public function __construct(){
           $this->Companies_db = $this->load->database( 'companies', TRUE, TRUE );

           // Pass reference of database to the CI-instance
           $CI =& get_instance();
           $CI->Companies_db =& $this->Companies_db;  
     }
}
```